# color of the knob cannot be updated after server data request

Tags: javascript, angularjs

After returning data from server request, the color of the knob cannot be updated as like as given image link [screencast](http://screencast.com/t/Ueeonnx4) . My code is given below:

JavaScript Code

```
$scope.options = { /* knob option */   };

$http
   .get(url)
   .then(function(res) {
      $scope.details = res.data.rating  // need to show $scope.details in knob 
   }, function(err) {});
```

html code

```
<ui-knob value="details" options="options "></ui-knob>
```

**NB:** I'm using [ng-knob](https://github.com/RadMie/ng-knob)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this problem by using the following code :

```
angular.module('', [])
 .controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
     $scope.options = { /* knob option */   };
     $scope.details = 0;  // value initialize
     $http
        .get(url)
        .then(function(res) {
            $timeout(function() {
               $scope.details = res.data.rating  // load data from server   
            }, 1000);                             
         }, function(err) {});
 });
```

Comment: $timeout do start $scope.$digest, and you can just connect your context, look at: .then($scope.yourCallback.bind(this)) and success

Answer (score 0):

//1. your code is async
//2. you need use 1. promise or 2. resolve in your router or 3. $scope.apply() after get response in your controller

//Prime 1 (Promise):

//code in Controller

```
var vm = this;
vm.asyncGreet = function () {
    var deferred = $q.defer();


    $http({
        method: 'post',
        data: $httpParamSerializerJQLike({
            //***your-send-data***
        }),
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
        url: ''//***your-url***
    }).
        success(function (data, status) {
            deferred.resolve('true');
        });
    return deferred.promise;
};

var promise = vm.asyncGreet();
promise.then(function (greeting) {
    //alert('Success: ' + greeting);

    //YOUR CODE AFTER SERVER REQUEST
    $scope.details = res.data.rating;

}, function (reason) {
    //alert('Failed: ' + reason);
}, function (update) {
    //alert('Got notification: ' + update);
});
```

//Prime 2 (Resolve in your Route)

```
(function (angular) {
    'use strict';

    // route-config.js
    angular
        .module('app')
        .config(config);

    config.$inject = ['$routeProvider'];
    function config($routeProvider) {
        console.log('routeConfig');
        $routeProvider
            .when('/requests', {
                templateUrl: '/tpl.html',
                controller: 'requestController',
                controllerAs: 'vm',
                //(Promise) IS REQUEST TO SERVER, AFTER START requestController
                resolve: {
                    requestPrepService: requestPrepService
                }
            });
    }
    requestPrepService.$inject =  ['requestService'];
    function requestPrepService(requestService) {
        //This $http response 
        return requestService.getRequests();
    }


    })(window.angular);


//in Controller


.$inject = ['requestPrepService'];
 vm.request = {
    data: requestPrepService.data,
 }
```

//**Addition**

```
1. If you use promise do not forget $inject = ['$q']
2. Please, read https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak
 (
 how use:
 <div ng-controller="yourController" ng-cloak></div>
 )
```

Comment: Are you using the knob to control anything else? I found this knob interesting because it was Angular compatible and reportedly supported touch/change events. But it does not emit anything, so I was wondering how it is done.